# Book or article on Bernoulli numbers and polynomials

Tags: book-recommendation, article-writing

I am looking for a book or article that deals in detail with the Bernoulli numbers and polynomials.

Comment: Read [Bernoulli Manifesto](http://luschny.de/math/zeta/The-Bernoulli-Manifesto.html) by Peter Luschny.